# Cannot Connect Jconsole to Websphere SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jmx, jconsole

I am having trouble connecting WebSphere with Jconsole through an SSL connection. I have generate my own keystore and truststore with certificates and I have setup the following system properties through WebSphere:

```
-Dcom.ibm.team.server.monitoring.mbean.server=WebSphere -Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12099 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore={KEYSTOREPATH}\keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

On the jconsole side I am running the following arguments to add the truststore files to the runtime:

```
jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore={KEYSTOREPATH}\truststore -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs12 -J-Djava.security.debug=all localhost:12099
```

With the debug mode, I am able to see the error on the client side:

```
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
at com.ibm.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:724)
at com.ibm.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:698)
at com.ibm.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:254)
at com.ibm.security.util.DerInputStream.getDerValue(DerInputStream.java:499)
at com.ibm.security.pkcsutil.PKCSDerObject.decode(PKCSDerObject.java:251)
at com.ibm.security.pkcs12.PFX.<init>(PFX.java:134)
at com.ibm.crypto.provider.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1225)
at com.ibm.jsse2.cc.a(cc.java:72)
at com.ibm.jsse2.cc.a(cc.java:76)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ec.g(ec.java:7)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ec.<init>(ec.java:19)
at com.ibm.jsse2.ec.e(ec.java:14)
at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.<init>(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:16)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1617)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:37)
at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.getDefaultClientSocketFactory(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:218)
at javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:128)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:625)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:228)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:214)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:353)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.checkSslConfig(ProxyClient.java:230)
at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.<init>(ProxyClient.java:133)
at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.getProxyClient(ProxyClient.java:487)
at sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole$3.run(JConsole.java:551)
```

Research tells me that the issue might be with the format of the keystore and truststore which in my case is PKCS12. The default is expecting JKS and I have changed this in the java.security file in the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security:

```
#
# Default keystore type.
#
keystore.type=pkcs12
```

Also, I have client authentication disabled.

Does anyone know what the issue might be with my setup?

Comment: You don't need PKCS12 for a truststore, and shouldn't _have_ the privatekey in a _remote_ truststore. Best way: get _only_ the _cert_, and put it in a jks, or a pkcs12 if you prefer and can (Sun/Oracle keytool before 8 can't do cert-only pkcs12, I don't know IBM). If you really want the full pkcs12, confirm it is exactly the same size as on the origin system (not truncated, padded, or any LF/CRLF change) and has the same checksum (usually md5sum or sha1sum is convenient). If you have or can get openssl, try `openssl pkcs12 -in file` and see what errors if any it gives.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 hi just a clarification with checksum, you mean I should check if the keystore and truststore checksum are in fact the same?

Comment: Yes. Or as I would put it, the copy of the keystore you are using as a truststore (on the client), versus the original keystore (on the server).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The checksums for both are not the same. But I feel that makes sense as the keystore has the private key but the truststore does not. I have used the following guide to create my keystore/truststore and from my understanding only the certificate is present in the truststore http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant 'keystore and truststore' as one thing. Did you use `keytool` from Sun/Oracle Java 6 as you linked to? If so, your truststore can't be pkcs12 because 6 and 7 don't do cert-only pkcs12 -- but you appear to be using IBM Java which has different crypto. Try being explicit: `keytool -list -keystore PATH/truststore -storetype jks` and again with `-storetype pkcs12`. Whichever works you should use, either defaulted in `java.security` or explicit in `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` (you don't need both).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am using WebSphere so I am using IBM java as a result which defaults to pkcs12. The commands that I have provided in the link are the same ones I used and the result were in pkcs12 format. I am not sure if this is the issue but I am trying to use Oracle java as well to see if I can get different results

Comment: As I said, try `keytool -list -storetype pkcs12`. (Oracle vs IBM shouldn't matter for keytool but try both if you like) If that works your program should also. If it doesn't, your file either isn't pkcs12 in the first place or is damaged somehow.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 this doesn't work, but don't I need to specify the keystore as well? For example -keystore key.p12

Comment: Yes `keytool -list` requires `-keystore $filename`; I thought that was clear from previous comment and I was just reemphasizing the _explicit_ `-storetype pkcs12` to be combined with `keytool -list`.